# Cannot get variable from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pyqt5

im trying to access a variable from another class but it keeps saying that the variable doesnt exist.

Here is the code for the first class:

```
class ConsoleClass(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(Console, self).__init__(parent)
    self.console = QPlainTextEdit()
```

And i want to get the "self.console" variable from it but it would work:

```
class myEditor(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(myEditor, self).__init__(parent)

    self.otherConsole = ConsoleClass.console
```

When i try doing "ConsoleClass().console" and access like this , i get this error:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted
```

how to reproduce:

```
class ConsoleClass(QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(Console, self).__init__(parent)
      self.console = QPlainTextEdit()


class myEditor(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self, parent = None):
          super(myEditor, self).__init__(parent)
          self.otherConsole = ConsoleClass.console #doesnt work
```

Im not sure how can i access the console variable in ConsoleClass from myEditor class.

Comment: `console` is an instance attribute, you try to access it on the class.

Comment: Ok so how do i get it from the "myEditor" class then?

Comment: `ConsoleClass().console` might give you what you want but not really sure if you want that...

Comment: The `console` attribute only exists when you create an _instance_ of `ConsoleClass`.  It does not exist on the class by itself, but that's how you're trying to access it.

Comment: `myEditor.__init__` should probably take an instance of `ConsoleClass` as an argument, so that you can associate your editor window with a particular console.

Comment: So should i just do ```class myEditor(QMainWindow, Console):``` ?? Or what exactly?

Comment: How exactly do i myEditor.__init__ take an instance of ConsoelClass ? @chepner

Comment: @ihatestackoverflow please provide a [mre] and read [ask], also review the [tour]

Comment: I just added how to reproduce please check it out and open my question again

Comment: @eyllanesc pleae re-open my questions im trying to find a solution and i alrady updated it and added a reproducible example

Comment: @ihatestackoverflow Your code is not an MRE, please read the links and check other SO posts where they provide an MRE and you know the SO rules.  .Try Change `self.otherConsole = ConsoleClass.console` to `self.otherConsole_instance = ConsoleClass()` `self.otherConsole = self.otherConsole_instance.console`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make public variables, or define the variables outside the classes. Hope I could help you